# Insert data into database PDO error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to get log in details from the user once they have logged in, into a server. I have attempted to use this:

```
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user_login",'root','');
  global $dbh;
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO login_details (browser, date_time, ip_address, username) VALUES (:browser, :date_time, :ip_address, :username)");
  $stmt->bindParam(':browser', $browser);
  $stmt->bindParam(':date_time', $date_time);
  $stmt->bindParam(':ip_address', $ip_address);
  $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);

  $browser = 'one';
  $value = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
  $stmt->execute();

  $date_time = 'one';
  $value = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
  $stmt->execute();

  $ip_address = 'one';
  $value = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $stmt->execute();

  $username = 'one';
  $value = $name;
  $stmt->execute();
```

Sorry if I have got this completely wrong, I am completely new to this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your script you are using `$conn` as the object connecting to the database, so why are you using the global `$dbh`. Just use `$conn` in place of `$dbh`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in another answer, you need to be consistent with your calls to your PDO object. Use `$conn` instead of `$dbh`, or vice versa.

Your current code also executes your SQL query mutliple times, specifically each time you call `$stmt->execute()`. In most of the cases, you haven't even assigned values to your bound parameters yet.

Your `$value` variables also missed the mark. You simply need to assign the desired value to the variables named in the `bindParam` calls.

Try this

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=user_login",'root','');
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO login_details (browser, date_time, ip_address, username) VALUES (:browser, :date_time, :ip_address, :username)");

$stmt->bindParam(':browser', $browser);
$stmt->bindParam(':date_time', $date_time);
$stmt->bindParam(':ip_address', $ip_address);
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);

$browser = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
$date_time = date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A');
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$username = $name;

$stmt->execute();
```